# countif importrange to count non blank cells which don't contain the string NA

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to count how many cells on a sheet have non blank values but don't contain the string "NA".  How can I do so?

I have tried =COUNTIF(IMPORTRANGE("url", "Sheet and data range"), "<> NA" but that just returns a count of all of the values which aren't blank.

Comment: Your narrative seems to contradict itself from paragraph to paragraph. Sample data together with expected results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=countifs(importrange(" k e y "," r a n g e "),"<>NA",importrange(" k e y "," r a n g e "),"<>")
```

Two conditions are required and COUNTIF only accepts one.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.